# Find out whether elements are unique within a certain range without having to program a macro in VBA: Is there a formula that can do that?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

Is there any way to find out, with the help of a formula, whether all elements of a certain range are unique or not without having to program a macro in VBA?

Let us say that the elements in column `A` are `K1` in cell `A1`, `K2` in cell `A2` and so on. I now want to check whether all of the elements in column `A` are unique or not. If they are unique, return `True` in cell `B1`, if they are not, return `False`.

It would be great if this could also work for checking rows so that a formula can, for instance, find out whether all elements in row `1` are unique or not and return `True` if they are and `False` when they are not.

Comment: yeah sure there, show us an example of your range

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this formula (adjust range appropriately):

```
=COUNTA(A1:A4)=COUNTA(UNIQUE(A1:A4))
```

[image]

To ignore blanks, you can filter them out before using `UNIQUE`. Like this:

```
=COUNTA(A1:A4)=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A4,A1:A4<>"")))
```

Comment: Ok, this is very good! Is there a way to exclude empty cells from the range? If, for example, `A2` and `A3` are empty and `A1` contains `K1` and `A4` contains `K4`, return `True`?

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: Do you also know how this works when checking elements of a certain row? `=COUNTA(A2:D2)=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:D2,A2:D2<>"")))`, for example, does not seem to work analogously.

Comment: In that case I believe you would need to wrap both ranges inside the FILTER function with TRANSPOSE

Comment: @Nemgathos switch the UNIQUE to columns: `=COUNTA(A2:D2)=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:D2,A2:D2<>""),TRUE))`